# Spring Flex - Interceptor - Cannot find class [flex.springintegration.core.DataServicesConfigProcessor]

Tags: spring, apache-flex, blazeds, lcds

I use Spring BlazeDS for integration between Flex and Spring in my Application Java EE.

Versions :

- spring-flex.version : 1.5.2.RELEASE
- lcds.version : 4.7

When i use :

```
<flex:message-broker />
```

It work fine.

But when i use interceptor, i have the following error :

```
<bean id="messageInterceptor" class="com.package.MessageInterceptorImpl"/>
<flex:message-broker>
        <flex:message-interceptor ref="messageInterceptorImpl"/>
</flex:message-broker>
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [flex.springintegration.core.DataServicesConfigProcessor] for bean with name '_messageBrokerDataServicesConfigProcessor' defined in null; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: flex.springintegration.core.DataServicesConfigProcessor
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the error states: he can't find the class flex.springintegration.core.DataServicesConfigProcessor
Add the class to the runtime environment and you'll be good to go.

Most likely you are missing an jar file containing this class.

Comment: With the LCDS or BlazeDS installer come a few jar files like 'flex-messaging-*.jar' most likely it will be in there. Having them at build time is something else as having them available at runtime, keep that in mind.